# Typescript socket.io transpile error after recent update

Tags: node.js, typescript

After a recent update, I'm failing to transpile my node.js project: I get

```
node_modules/engine.io-parser/build/esm/commons.d.ts:7:81 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Blob'.

7 export declare type RawData = string | Buffer | ArrayBuffer | ArrayBufferView | Blob;
```

relevant part of package.json:

```
    "socket.io": "^4.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.2.0",
```

using npm 8.5.5, node v14.18.1, ubuntu 18.04 -- any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Hope you fixed it. You must include "dom" in tsconfig.json 'lib' array to get this type, so the error will be gone by that way.

Comment: thanks. I fixed it, don't remember how...